# How to set number of partition when migrating from BoneCp to HikariCP

Tags: postgresql, hikaricp, bonecp

I am in the process of changing BoneCp to access our postgres database to HikariCp. Can someone help me with specifying the partition count in HikariConfig.

From:

```
            BoneCPConfig config = new BoneCPConfig();
            config.setIdleMaxAge(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            config.setIdleConnectionTestPeriod(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            config.setMaxConnectionAge(30, TimeUnit.MINUTES);
            config.setJdbcUrl(dbUrl);
            config.setMaxConnectionsPerPartition(64);
            config.setMinConnectionsPerPartition(1);
            config.setPartitionCount(4);    <--------- Specified partition count is 4
```

To:

```
            HikariConfig hikariConfig = new HikariConfig();
            hikariConfig.setIdleTimeout(Duration.ofMinutes(10).toMillis());
            hikariConfig.setKeepaliveTime(Duration.ofSeconds(30).toMillis());
            hikariConfig.setMaxLifetime(Duration.ofMinutes(30).toMillis());
            hikariConfig.setJdbcUrl(dbUrl);
            hikariConfig.setMaximumPoolSize(64);
```

What is the equivalent way to `setPartitionCount` in `hikariConfig`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no such concept as connections partitions in HikariCP, so to match number of connections what you want is to set hikariCP maximumPoolSize to be equal to boneCP `maxConnectionsPerPartition*PartitionsCount` that is `64*4=256` in your case.

Note, that you might not need that big amount of connections anymore as HikariCP should manage them more efficiently, but anyway I wouldn’t advise to change the pool and maximum pool size at once.